# How to autogenerate Getters from a json file in Pycharm

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pycharm, getter

I have really big `config.json` file that I am trying to read and generate getters from in `pycharm IDE`.

Sample `config.json` looks like this (`. . .` indicates lot of similar items) :

```
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  .
  .
  .
  "key1000" : value1000
}
```

My python `ConfigRead.py` class looks like something like this :

```
import json


class ConfigRead(object):

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        json_content = open(file_path).read()
        self.jsonData = json.loads(json_content)

    def get_config(self):
        return self.jsonData

    def get_key1(self):
        return self.jsonData["key1"]
```

Now typing a `1000` getters is something I don't want to attempt.

`Eclipse` had autogeneration approach from config files. I have migrated to `PyCharm` & I am not able to figure it out.

Any leads will be helpful - to simply this process. Thanks.

I am also open to any suggestions if you see this as a bad approach in `python`. I am open to changing my design if it simplifies & makes things more manageable.

Comment: This is a bad approach in any programming language. Rather than `key1` to `keyN`, why not use a list (JSON array) instead?

Comment: I don't have a control to change the schema of the json file today.

Comment: But  you can change how it's represented in code. Also, getters themselves aren't pythonic.

Comment: can u help me understand the approach you are suggesting, with an example pls? This `config-reader` would be used to start a `flask-microservice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered implementing `__getitem__` instead? `__getitem__` is the magic method that lets you use the `[]` operator, which I think is a much more sustainable approach to what you're trying to do, because it doesn't require you to change your source code every time the configuration file changes. I don't know what your specific use-case is, but something like:

```
class ConfigRead(object):

  def __init__(self, file_path):
      json_content = open(file_path).read()
      self.jsonData = json.loads(json_content)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
      return self.jsonData[key]
```

Would let you write stuff like:

```
config = ConfigRead("path/to/file")
name = config['key1']
```

Or, if you don't have any additional processing you want to do on the config data, you could just use the JSON data directly, like this:

```
def read_config(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as config_file:
        return json.load(config_file)

config = read_config("path/to/file")
name = config['key1']
```

Comment: Thanks @Tutleman, Yes this is something I was going to have as a backup. The problem with this approach is the keys are not abstracted into the code, which means if a service developer consumes this he/she will can feed in a non-existent key. To avoid that I wanted to have the above approach.

Comment: @sudhishkr Are you talking about a consumer trying to read nonexistent values? If so, there's not much to be done about that - a developer could just as easily (depending on their IDE, if any) mistype the name of the getter. In that case, an `AttributeError` would be raised. In this case, it'll cause a `KeyError`.

Comment: yes you understood me correctly. I think thats a not-so-complicated & decent change to my current approach.Thanks!